# Limit container resources both using --memory and --cgroup-parent

Tags: memory, docker, limit, cgroups

I'd like to limit both total memory consumption for a group of containers as well as memory consumption for a particular container.

Say, a container is allowed to consume not greater than 1Gb and all containers are allowed to consume 4Gb max.

The question is:

Will I achieve my goal if I create a cgroup with 4Gb memory limit then run my containers as the following:

```
docker run --memory=1G --cgroup-parent=my-4Gb-cgroup <image-id>
```